# Android localization and SDK support differences

Tags: android, localization, android-sdk-1.6

The localization language support in Android 1.6 is a lot less than the languages that are supported in more recent versions. And I know that Google is making a concerted effort to expand their reach in more languages and countries.

I've looked high and low for an answer to this question, and perhaps it is answered on the developer site, or perhaps answered in a different context.. but I couldn't find it.

The question is, if I were to create the relative folders and assets for every language possible (using the some-odd 90+ locale codes), will later versions of Android automatically pick those up when they're eventually supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - yes. All files are loaded at runtime using the API level available on the device.

Comment: Great, thank you. I do have another question that involves supporting large screens that don't 'exist' in the old version of Android, but I'll leave that for another question. Thanks again! (btw, is your answer located anywhere in the official SDK docs?)

Comment: I believe I saw it somewhere, but can't find it right now. Anyway I know it from experience.